# 'The Android emulator exited with code -11 during startup' error is showing on vs code, Is there any solution?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, vulkan, flutter-exception

Following is the error, when i run the command 'flutter emulators --launch Pixel_3a_API_25' in VS Code:

[Image of the error (output of 'flutter emulators --launch Pixel_3a_API_25' command)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhL9f.png)

[Output of the command 'flutter emulators'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGkcA.png)

[Output of the command 'flutter doctor -v'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7bnF.png)

How do i resolve this error? **btw i'm using Garuda Linux system, if that helps**

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Flutter using snap?  This issue has been reported with this installation previously. Try to launch the emulator using Android studio, to rule out if it's an avd problem or flutter installation problem.
Also try launching it using `emulator -avd`and report back please.

Comment: Yes, i installed flutter using snap, and i can use emulators in android-studio but i usually works in VS Code. What you meant by "emulator -avd", is it a command?

Comment: Yes, for example `emulator -list-avds`, checkout this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: Also, this a problem reported in snap installs. I'd recommend installing it using the .tar.